# struggeling with matrix and their positions

Tags: python, loops, matrix

I am trying to solve this program (python) where having a matrix I should show every row, every position and his value

I am trying this sentence but it is not working:

```
m = [
    [3, 8, 2],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [4, 2, 9]
]



for i in range(len(m)):
    print('the row number',i+1,'and the position',m[0][i],'has a value of',m[i][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a nested loop to print on each raw and each col:

```
m = [
    [3, 8, 2],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [4, 2, 9]
]

for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m[i])):
        print('the row number', i + 1, 'and the position', j + 1, 'has a value of', m[i][j])
```

which gives

```
the row number 1 and the position 1 has a value of 3
the row number 1 and the position 2 has a value of 8
the row number 1 and the position 3 has a value of 2
the row number 2 and the position 1 has a value of 2
the row number 2 and the position 2 has a value of 3
the row number 2 and the position 3 has a value of 1
the row number 3 and the position 1 has a value of 4
the row number 3 and the position 2 has a value of 2
the row number 3 and the position 3 has a value of 9
```